# Pandas dataframe calculate average of n-columns for each row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given following `pandas` dataframe of `248 rows x 101 cols`, I need to calculate a new column containing the average of all the `sim-*` columns only (exclude the `Date` column).

[image]

Comment: please the guidelines here and post data as text to help reproduce, instead of images  https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is one way to do it. if you post the data as text, I can add the result here

```
df.filter(like='sim-', axis=1).mean(axis=1)
```